# Where can I find poker hand histories?

Tags: game-mechanics

Do poker games get annotated at all? Is there some notations to log who bet how much and how the game developed?

Comment: Which poker games? All online sites will have ways for you to download the hand history for later viewing.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer: I mean not my own poker hands, but games in a tournament.

Comment: Annotated poker hands are pretty much found on _poker videos_. About notations, all history logs cover also your opponents like "X bets that", this is as close you can get by logs.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific tournament?  If not, searching the google for "hand history review" will give you lots of videos where various poker players discussing their run in some tournament or another.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer "All" online sites?

Comment: @Michael If you're looking to be pedantic, then just point out where that's not true. An online site where you can't review your hand histories is a site where few serious players would want to play.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer I've never been on a site or app that had hand histories and I've been on several (WSOP being the most recent), but then again, I live in a part of the world where playing for money online is illegal, or at least due to current laws it's virtually impossible to actually play online for real money.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous web sites that sell hand histories from the major sites (search for buy poker hand history). Lots of players also post interesting hands on forums (www.pokerforums.org, twoplustwo.com, etc) many pros post their hands with their analyses (or your hands with their analyses) in videos on youtube.

I don't know if any standardized method for noting hand histories, everyone has their own approach. The file formats used by the major sites (pokerstars etc) are defacto standards since their are many tools that can read them.

If you just want to click through hands with minimal discussion check out sharemypair.com; I don't like their mobile app b/c it seems to want every access right my phone can control however you can view hands on the site without issue.